# To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error as I wrote on the title above. I'm a new learner in flutter, I have seeking for some solution to solve it, example this link below.

But I still cannot solve the problem can anyone help me on that?
I know this might be a duplicate question, I have try my best to understand it and still cannot solve, can anyone help out? Thanks. And
below is the main.dart code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sharing_app/MyFlutterApp_icons.dart';
import 'package:sharing_app/Sharer.dart';
import 'package:sharing_app/Customer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainPage());

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{
  Home createState()=> Home();
}

class Home extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Welcome',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.black87,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: RaisedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return Sharer();
                          }
                      )
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.account_circle,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      'Login as Sharer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'MyFlutterApp',
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: RaisedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return Customer();
                          }
                      )
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.account_circle,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      'Login as Customer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'MyFlutterApp',
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error : it tells on the android studio console "A build function returned null.". Then, "To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)"."

Can anyone help out?

Comment: As the error clearly suggests just put the `return` before `Scaffold`. You must understand that you have to return a `Widget` from the build function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just forget the `return` statement before your Scafffold :

```
class Home extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
```

The build method expect a Widget (in you case the scaffold) to be return so it can draw / build this widget.